# How to choose the bounds for the integral when calculating a marginal distribution from a joint distribution?

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

Let $f(x,y)=2x$ for $0 < x < y < 1$ and zero otherwise. I would like to find the marginal distribution $f_{X}(x)$, which is equal to $$\int f(x,y)dy.$$
However, should integrate over $[0, y]$ or $[0, 1]$? Why?

Comment: For fixed $x$, what are the possible values for $y$?

Comment: So if $x$ is fixed, it could be anything between $0$ and $y$. So when taking the integral, I should integrate over $[x, 1]$, since $x<y$ and $y<1$?

Comment: $y \in (x, 1)$ for fixed $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate over the support of $y$ which in this case is $(x,1)$ by the definition of the bounds on $x$ and $y$ given in the question.

To be explicit, in order to obtain the marginal distribution of $X$ you need to solve the following:

$$f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int_x^1 2x dy$$